# Using Groovy in JMeter to query Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, groovy, jmeter

I am new and this is probably a very basic question, but I didn't find a good sample that works for me. In JMeter 3.3 I set JSR223 Sampler to query several parameters in mongo db. I succeeded to connect to mongo and do a count on collection, now I need to query by _id. I later on need to count number of elements in array. So far even find by id didn't work. 
Working part:

```
import com.gmongo.*;
import com.mongodb.*;
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.mongodb.config.MongoDBHolder;
import com.mongodb.DBCollection;                    // import DBCollection class

DB db = MongoDBHolder.getDBFromSource("mongo", "Users");
DBCollection collection = db.getCollection("DownloadTracking"); // get "zips" collection
long count = collection.getCount();
String result = String.valueOf(count);              // convert long to String
SampleResult.setResponseData(result.getBytes());
```

Now not working samples:

```
log.info db.collection.findOne()

2018-02-04 16:36:19,826 ERROR o.a.j.p.j.s.JSR223Sampler: Problem in JSR223 script JSR223 Sampler, message: javax.script.ScriptException: javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: collection for class: com.mongodb.DBApiLayer
```

Actually I need to get response for this object:

```
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("EntityOwner.UserId", ObjectId("544e0e6dcbda7101b0148739")); // create DBObject holding the query
DBObject result1 = collection.findOne(query);  // execute the query and store outcome into "result" DBObject
SampleResult.setResponseData(result1.toString().getBytes()); // set JSR223 sampler response to "result"
```

Error:

```
2018-02-04 16:55:24,197 ERROR o.a.j.p.j.s.JSR223Sampler: Problem in JSR223 script JSR223 Sampler, message: javax.script.ScriptException: javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.ObjectId() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [544e0e6dcbda7101b0148739]
Possible solutions: inject(groovy.lang.Closure)
javax.script.ScriptException: javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.ObjectId() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [544e0e6dcbda7101b0148739]
Possible solutions: inject(groovy.lang.Closure)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:158) ~[groovy-all-2.4.12.jar:2.4.12]
    at javax.script.AbstractScriptEngine.eval(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_152]
    at org.apache.jmeter.util.JSR223TestElement.processFileOrScript(JSR223TestElement.java:222) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.JSR223Sampler.sample(JSR223Sampler.java:69) [ApacheJMeter_java.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:498) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:424) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:255) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_152]
```

I tried putting an object in JSON format, like: `.findOne({ "EntityOwner.UserId": ObjectId("544e0e6dcbda7101b0148739")})`. It didn't work.

Comment: Try add `import org.bson.types.ObjectId`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try amending your query as follows:

```
def query = new BasicDBObject()
query.put('EntityOwner.UserId', new org.bson.types.ObjectId('544e0e6dcbda7101b0148739'))
def result1 = collection.findOne(query)
```

References:

- [ObjectId](http://api.mongodb.com/java/current/org/bson/types/ObjectId.html) JavaDoc
- [BasicDBObject](http://api.mongodb.com/java/current/com/mongodb/BasicDBObject.html) JavaDoc
- [How to Load Test MongoDB with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-mongodb-jmeter)

Comment: Great, this resolved the issue. Thanks a lot for your help.